# Upload to Blob Storage while overwriting existing Blob

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

When using the StorageClient and calling UploadByteArray() with a blob name that already exists, will this cause any data corruption ? (In other words, do I have to call Delete() before uploading, which will cost another transaction ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just be able to call `UploadByteArray()` without having to do the delete first and it will overwrite the blob that is already there.

Comment: And what happens if I'm uploading blob which is readed right now? Will be readed during uploading? Is there any transaction in Azure?

Comment: My guess is that it will read the non-updated version of the file, but this is a question all by itself.